# VBA - Create an array of all table names in workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My end goal here is to have a button, that when pressed creates a new sheet with a table on it.. that new table should be added to the PivotTable Wizard list.

The error being called is

error message 1004 PivotTableWizard method of Worksheet failed

```
Dim NewShop As Variant
NewShop = InputBox("What Shop are you creating a new estimate sheet for? (example: Shop 18)")

NewShop = Replace(NewShop, " ", "_")

Sheets("CE_Template").Select
Sheets("CE_Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Project Estimator")
ActiveSheet.Name = NewShop

If ActiveSheet.Name = "CE_Template" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Range("C4").Value = NewShop
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name = NewShop
End If

Dim MyArray() As String
Dim ArraySize As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

ArraySize = 0

ReDim MyArray(0 To 0)

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(ArraySize) As String
        MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = tbl.Name & "[#All]"
        ArraySize = ArraySize + 1
    Next tbl
Next ws

Sheets("Project Estimator").Select
Range("A17").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:=MyArray
```

Edit: my previous question was how to add items to the array, that has since been solved. Thank you. Please see new question.

Comment: What do you mean "It gets stuck"? Is it throwing an error? Which error? On what line?

Comment: it throws an error on MyArray(ArraySize) = tbl.Name & "[#All]" - the error is "scriptage out of range"

Comment: You have a 1 dimensional array and you're trying to put a table into it?

Comment: I believe you need to loop through your array and convert it into a single string that the PivotTable wizard will recognize as input. Try experimenting with the Macro Recorder to see what it's looking for exactly.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new PivotTable? If yes, you must use PivotTables.Add method before you can use PivotTableWizard. If you want to update an existing table use ChangePivotCache

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your immediate problem, you need to add this line before your loop:

`ReDim MyArray(0 To 0)`

When you `Dim MyArray()` you are creating an array with no indices, so you can't assign any values to it without using `ReDim` first.

You also need to change the `ReDim` in your loop to `ReDim Preserve`. If you just use `ReDim` it will destroy your array contents every time.

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes.

Still no solution for updating the PivotTableWizard